# What does x denote in Github file change log

Tags: github

[image]

I am seeing these X signs in front of the lines added, what does these denote?

Comment: What do you mean with "Github online"?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, red lines in change log indicates that the lines are deleted, and green line indicates that new lines are added. X denotes that there is a conflict with main branch (default branch) or with newer versions of that file, or there are some tests failing.

Comment: Github is not showing me any conflicts though in the PR :|

Comment: @AdilMahmood Maybe there are some mandatory/non-mandatory test(s) failing because of these lines. Are you able to merge your changes in the main repo?

Comment: Yes, I can go ahead and merge my changes and there are no test failures as well

Comment: Great to hear that!